# tableview formatting in objective c

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

i declared array of strings... which contains

```
array[0]= abc;2658;589;25
array[1]= pwwqr;235;555;50
array[2]= bec;56;53;23
array[3]= aabr;26;49;4
array[4]= ghc;2228;529;27
.
.
.
```

i want output like this

```
abc
2658
589
25
pwwqr
235
555
50
bec
.
.
.
```

means when ; comes in string, it should go in newline finally i want to store this things in newarray.

Comment: dude i separated value in array now i want answer like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399550/mapping-tableview-with-label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableViewCell does not provide a way to display the information the way you want. Just sSubclass UITableViewCell and add 4 UILabels to it. Create a setter for each of them.

Comment: ya i created 4 labels now i want output in above format.. how should i do this ?

Comment: **Sublass** UITableViewCell and use the addSubview method to add the labels to your custom UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: can ne 1 give answer of this                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399550/mapping-tableview-with-label